# Empty PhotoStream-folder on Window

Tags: icloud, windows, photo-stream

I have installed iCloud Control Panel on my Windows PC. During setup, I was asked to create folders for both the PhotoStream and my uploads. I've done all that, but the issue is that I can't see my photos. The folder is even empty. On my iPhone however, all photos are listed in the Photostream.
How can I view my photos on my Windows PC?

Comment: Give it some time to sync both you PC and your iCloud. Also, are you behind a proxy or do you have any other restrictions installed?

Comment: How can i check restrictions ?

Comment: Proxy, firewall settings, do you own an company PC,...

Comment: yes, no issues with the proxy and firewall settings.

Comment: How long ago have you configured the iCloud control panel?

Comment: 2 Days before. Does it depends on time ?

Comment: No, iCloud just needs some time to sync. Are you sure you're looking in the right folder and you've activated PhotoStream in the control panel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4798/discussion-between-venkat-manohar-and-michiel)

Comment: Is there any indication when syncing is happening, like say the Notification Icon in Dropbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to reset the iCloud settings. There are different ways to do so.

1. Try to close the iCloud control panel and then quit all Apple and iCloud processes by using the task manager. If you reopen the iCloud control panel, chances are good your photos will start syncing.
2. Otherwise try to uncheck en re-check the PhotoStream option in your control panel (don't forget to hit the 'Apply' button).
3. A last solutions is to uninstall and re-install the iCloud control panel, which will reset the iCloud settings as well.

Comment: Couldn't find still my photos :(

Comment: I've got the same exact problem.  I've tried all three suggestions to no avail.  I've even tried to delete my icloud account from my phone and then reinstall it.  My photo stream on my PC is empty and it once used to work very nicely.  I could move any photos from there to shared photo streams but not anymore and there are NO error messages at all.

Comment: I couldn't get my photos syncing even after re-installing :(

Answer (score 1):

I've found iCloud Photo syncing for Windows to be incredibly unreliable.

After multiple re-installs of the iCloud Control Panel, and eventually moving to a new PC, it never syncs photos reliably. The best it can do is show the oldest several photos that's still in my iCloud Photo Stream when I happened to install it. They never go away and the folder is never updated again...

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign out of the iCloud Control Panel
2. Uninstall iCloud
3. Delete all iCloud folders from your computer. (I used Everything to find all folders matching "icloud")
4. Run CCleaner and "Scan Registry for Issues" to purge registry entries left behind by iCloud
5. Download iCloud Control Panel
6. Re-install iCloud Control Panel
7. Reboot the computer
8. Start iCloud and sign in again
9. Ensure that iCloud photos are enabled

If that doesn't work give up and https://www.icloud.com/#photos and download your photos from their webpage or use Dropbox or some other photo syncing method. [Syncing is hard and hardware companies can't normally write very good software](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/10/18/forbes-apple-tried-to-buy-dropbox/)